# Initial error when querying SQL Server 2012 database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Using SQL Server 2012, I created a database and a table:

[image]

When I query the table the first time (after I connect to SQL Server) using this query:

```
select * 
from [dbo].[Downloads]
```

I get

> Msg 2809, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The request for procedure 'Downloads' failed because 'Downloads' is a table object.

But the second time I execute the same `SELECT` statement, it runs correctly

How do I eliminate this error the first time around?

Comment: As in, you run it, this error comes up, then you execute again and it works? You aren't changing anything in between? Interesting...

Comment: @MatthewHaugen -  now, I don't change anything in between. Every time I log onto MS SQL Server and first run the command I get error, then each subsequent time (while I am still logged in) it works perfectly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You had the text `Downloads` selected in Management Studio. This causes the T-SQL string `Downloads` to be executed. Such a T-SQL batch is interpreted as a procedure call.

Comment: What a weired error message! I had to clear my selection some text in the query editor to avoid the error. Without your help, I wouldn't be able to survive the nasty error. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @YuShen the error message is like that because a batch consisting only of `Xyz` is defined to call procedure `Xyz`. I believe you can use this special syntax at the beginning of any batch. Probably a historic feature. SQL is very old and crappy.

Answer (score 0):

I made one column a primary key, now this issue disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, the explorer is not aware of the database you want to execute the command on.

To fix it be explicit in your script:

```
[dbname]
select * 
from [dbo].[Downloads]
```