# How to populate a table in SQL

Tags: sql

In table 1 of my database is a column called Product Title, some of the products have the same name. However, they have different prices.

There is also a column called Product Version. This could be filled with Sale Price, Master Retail Price, Black Friday Price.

For all of the the products that are not 'Master Retail Price', I need to populate the Master Retail Price product number in to the Main Product Number Column.

So for example: If there are three Items called Banana, I need the ones that are the sale versions to have the Main Product Number in the Main Product Number Column.

If the Product Version is 'Master Retail Price', then Main Product Number should be NULL for that row.

So far, the code I have inserts all the product numbers from table 1 into table 2. If anyone could help here I would greatly appreciate it.

```
Select [Table 1].[Product Title], [Table 1].[Product No]

FROM [Table 1] 

INNER JOIN [Table 2] ON [Table1].[Product Title]=[Table 2].[Product Title]

UPDATE [Table 1] 

SET [Table 1].[Main Product Number]=[Table1.[Product No] 

WHERE [Table 1].[Product Verison]='Master Retail Price';
```

Comment: you are pretty close... bit more try and understanding

Comment: You are using non-standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

OK, Let's reproduce what you have said

For this example I've used an Oracle Database.

We have table t1 with let's say 4 columns (the ones that you mentioned)

```
create table t1( 
main_product_number int, 
product_number int, 
product_title varchar2(20), 
product_version varchar2(40) );
```

Populate the table with some imaginary values

```
insert into t1 values (NULL, 1,'Banana','Master Retail Price');
insert into t1 values (5, 2, 'Banana','Sale Price');
insert into t1 values (7, 3, 'Banana','Black Friday Price');
```

Do a simple select to see the data:

```
select * from t1;

MAIN_PRODUCT_NUMBER PRODUCT_NUMBER  PRODUCT_TITLE   PRODUCT_VERSION
 -                  1               Banana          Master Retail Price
 5                  2               Banana          Sale Price
 7                  3               Banana          Black Friday Price
```

> For all of the the products that are not 'Master Retail Price', I need
>   to populate the Master Retail Price product number in to the Main
>   Product Number Column.

Hmmm... Let's use a correlated subquery for this task in a beautiful self join:

```
update t1 a
   set a.main_product_number=( select product_number
                                 from t1 b
                                where a.product_title = b.product_title
                                  and b.product_version='Master Retail Price'
                                   and b.main_product_number is null
                              )
 where a.product_version <> 'Master Retail Price';
```

Now all of the products that are not master retail price, their main product number will be populated with the master retail price product number, as you can see in the select bellow.

```
MAIN_PRODUCT_NUMBER PRODUCT_NUMBER  PRODUCT_TITLE   PRODUCT_VERSION
-                   1               Banana          Master Retail Price
1                   2               Banana          Sale Price
1                   3               Banana          Black Friday Price
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much GreenT, this worked. I have just managed to get my head around your code and have started to use this with a larger amount of data. An error has been thrown at me: "The request one for procedure T1 failed because T1 is a table object. I don't suppose you have come across this before or know of any idea what it could be?  Thanks again

Comment: @user20936 I'm happy to know that it worked for you, here is the response to your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/25270305/5063953